# How to compare two sheets in excel & output similarities AND differences?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a current code that compares the first two sheets and then outputs the differences in another. I am now trying to figure out how to also output the similarities into another worksheet.

Here is my current code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareIt()
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Var As Variant
    Dim v()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim str As String

    ar = Sheet1.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        ReDim v(1 To UBound(ar, 2))
        For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
            For n = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
                str = str & Chr(2) & ar(i, n)
                v(n) = ar(i, n)
            Next
            .Item(str) = v: str = ""
        Next
        ar = Sheet2.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(, UBound(v)).Value
        For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
            For n = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
                str = str & Chr(2) & ar(i, n)
                v(n) = ar(i, n)
            Next
            If .exists(str) Then
                .Item(str) = Empty
            Else
                .Item(str) = v
            End If
            str = ""
        Next
        For Each arr In .keys
            If IsEmpty(.Item(arr)) Then .Remove arr
        Next
        Var = .items: j = .Count
    End With
    With Sheet3.Range("a10").Resize(, UBound(ar, 2))
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Value = ar
        If j > 0 Then
            .Offset(1).Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Var))
        End If
    End With

    Sheet3.Activate
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you comparing rows?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is:

> *Any ideas?*

I do have an idea that does rely on:

- **Your excel license** *([`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function is available if you have Office 2019, or if you have an Office 365 subscription)*
- **Your data size** *(If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), `TEXTJOIN` returns the #VALUE! error.)*

But it's an idea :)

[image: Sheet1] [image: Sheet2]

Sheet1 & Sheet2

Run this code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Var() As String
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Var() = Split(Evaluate("=TEXTJOIN("","",TRUE,IF(Sheet1!A1:A6=TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A1:A5),Sheet1!A1:A6,""""))"), ",")
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Var) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Var)
End With

End Sub
```

Output on sheet3:

[image]

Obviously it's simplified, but you can add variables in the `EVALUATE`.

Comment: This assumes the user is using Office 365 as `TEXTJOIN()` is not a valid function in most other Excel versions.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs OP asked for ideas. I stated in my answer this does rely on his/her excel license. Also, I don't have 365 myself but Excel 2019 ;)

Comment: I am just pointing out to someone who may come back to down vote you because "it doesn't work", when it only didn't work because they aren't using the correct Excel version. And 2019 does include it, which is why is said _most other_ Excel versions :-). Not saying your answer is wrong by any means, but your answer probably should let users know that this would only work in those two Excel versions.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, got you. Will edit to elaborate on that a bit more.